# The issue with updating data in Tanstack React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm building an online store in React and decided to use React Query for the project. The task is to display and store products in the cache. From these products, I need to fetch the required one on the product page and render it. There are two scenarios:

1. The product is in the cache - I retrieve it from the cache and return it from the function.
2. It's not in the cache - I fetch it from the server, load it into the cache, and return it from the function.
   The problem is that I don't understand how to update the data in the cache.

Here's my custom hook:

```
// useProducts.ts

import { IProduct } from '@/interfaces/product.interface';
import ProductService from '@/services/product/product.service';
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const useProducts = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { data, isSuccess } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['products'],
    queryFn: () => ProductService.getAll({ page: 1, perPage: 9 }),
    select: ({ data }) => data,
  });

  const getProductById = async (productId: number) => {
    console.log("cached products: ", queryClient.getQueryCache().find({ queryKey: ['products'] })?.state.data?.data);
    const product = data?.products.find((p) => p.id === productId);
    if (!!product) return product;

    try {
      const response = await ProductService.getById(productId);
      
      queryClient.setQueryData<IProduct[]>(['products'], (state) => {
        console.log("state:", state);
        return [...(state || []), response];
      });

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching product by ID:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  return { data, isSuccess, getProductById };
};
```

```
// ProductService.ts

import { $axios } from '@/api/api.interceptor';
import { IProduct } from '@/interfaces/product.interface';
import {
  IProductResponse,
  ProductDataFiltersType,
  ProductDataType,
} from './product.types';

class ProductService {
  private url = '/product';

  getAll = async (queryData = {} as ProductDataFiltersType) => {
    return $axios.get<IProductResponse>(this.url, { params: queryData });
  };

  getById = async (id: string | number) => {
    // return $axios.get<IProduct>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
    const response = await $axios.get<IProduct>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
    return response.data;
  };

  ...
}

export default new ProductService();

export type IProductResponse = {
  products: IProduct[]
  currentPage: number
  totalPages: number
}
```

For some reason, when I call setQueryData, the axios response is in the state instead of the array of products (as I think it should work):

```
cached products: {products: Array(9), totalPages: 2, currentPage: 1}
state: {data: {products, currentPage, totalPages}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
```

Consequently, my error is -

```
useProducts.ts:42 Error fetching product by ID: TypeError: (state || []) is not iterable
    at useProducts.ts:25:21
    at functionalUpdate (@tanstack_react-query.js?v=6de31b48:42:42)
    at _a8.setQueryData (@tanstack_react-query.js?v=6de31b48:1538:18)
    at getProductById (useProducts.ts:24:19)
```

Btw, `products` in my Home.tsx works perfectly.

```
import CardsContainer from '@/components/shared/CardsContainer/CardsContainer';
import { useProducts } from '@/hooks/features/products/useProducts';
import { useActions } from '@/hooks/general/useActions';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Banner from './components/Banner/Banner';

function Home() {
  const { data, isSuccess } = useProducts();
  const { checkAuth } = useActions();

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="rows-container">
      <Banner />
      {isSuccess && data?.products && (
        <CardsContainer products={data.products} />
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

P.S.

1. Can you explain to a newbie the difference between setQueryData and setQueriesData?
2. Is there a way for me to see the data that React Query stores in the cache (Maybe there are some extensions)?

Comment: Your life would be made immensely simpler if you just had a useProductById hook that just uses a useQuery function directly and ignore the possibility that the product is in the products cache entirely. Stay away, as much as possible, from manually checking/manipulating the cache, pretend it doesn’t exist.

Comment: setQueriesData is used to update multiple queries while setQueryData is for a single query. setQueriesData internally calls setQueryData.
As for your second question, you can use Tanstack query devtools https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/devtools

Comment: What you are doing is also a common pattern to use two separate useQuery’s for. It’s not a special use case, it’s a well known one to have a list and detail view. This may help https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys#use-query-key-factories

Comment: How correct is it to use two useQuery (for all products and for each individual one)? It sounds kind of weird to me. It's like we're storing all the data in two copies.

Comment: If I store two useQuery, it may turn out like this: we went to the product page - it loaded into the useQuery for single products. Then we went to the main page and uploaded the goods to another useQuery for all products. And then, when we need to get something specific, there will be big problems.

Comment: @dyakonovr not at all. In practice, I’ve found manually manipulating caches to be much more error prone than having duplicated data in the cache (as long as it’s connected by query keys appropriately like in my second comment and can be invalidated together)

Comment: Moreover, what prompted my suggestion is getProductById has to be an async function, which means you’ll have to resort to the “old” useEffect way of fetching data anyway, which is exactly what react query’s API simplifies and avoids. Ignoring the cache as much as possible will lead to the fewest bugs

Comment: @AdamJenkins But then we will face the problem that I described above: some data is in all products, others are in single ones. If you can write a sample code, I will be very grateful to you, because I don't quite understand what you want to do yet

Comment: Define your problem more when you say “some data is in all products and others are in single ones”. What you say you want here is actually data normalization (de-duping things in the cache). The creator of the library has said that very very few applications ever need this (my own addition: even though a lot of people think they do). https://twitter.com/tannerlinsley/status/1557395389531074560?lang=en

Comment: Create a useProductById hook that accepts an id and just calls a useQuery function, and then try it to see if it works (or where/how it doesn’t). I’m very serious, do not be concerned about duplication in the cache, ignore the cache entirely and your life will be easier (but only if your API is well structured and allows you to). You’ll quickly discover if it “allows you to” or not - but only if you first ignore it entirely

Comment: Look, two scenarios: 1. We land on the website's main page where products are displayed - we retrieve them using useQuery(['products']). Then, we navigate to a specific product page - we fetch it from useQuery(['products']).
2. We were given a link to a product that isn't in the cache, so we need to load it and save it. According to your example, I should put it in useQuery(['product', productId]), but then there's an issue: for instance, if I refresh the page, it's unclear where I should fetch the data about the product from - useQuery(['products']) or useQuery(['product', productId]).

Comment: I'm bothered by the fact that there seem to be two separate states (cache for individual products and cache for all products), almost independent of each other.

Comment: @dyakonovr they should be independent of each other. Your product “list view” may have been filtered by the user (paginated, filters applied, etc). As for where you should fetch the products from - if you’re on a list view page, fetch it from the product list endpoint, if you’re on a detail view, fetch it from the detail endpoint. Ignore the cache, ignore the duplicate state. When you need to perform a mutation on a product, invalidate the products query key and your application will function just fine. It’s a difficult hurdle to jump, but make the leap and the simplicity will pay dividends

Comment: Here’s another point: if a user lands on a product detail page directly, you shouldn’t need to fetch the products list. This should illustrate to you that putting the list endpoint concern in the same hook as the detail endpoint concern as tightly coupling things that should be independent

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to set cache, all cache is settled by react-query automatically if you provide 'queryKey' when fetching the data.
2. To access the cache data you can use
   `const queryClient = useQueryClient()`
   `const data = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)`
3. The package '@tanstack/react-query' includes an asynchronous function that can be used to get an existing query's cached data. If the query does not exist fetchQuery will be called and its results returned.
   `const data = await queryClient.ensureQueryData({ queryKey, queryFn })`
   You can check the docs here - https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientensurequerydata